# Android - CheckedTextView checkbox does not conform with padding attribute?

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I have following xml code:

It seems like the textview reflects to the 10 dp padding however the checkbox on the right side does not.  The textview and checkbox are not aligned with each other.  Anyone know why the checkbox is not conforming to the 10 dp padding?  And is there a way to align my textview and checkbox?

```
<CheckedTextView 
    android:id="@+id/nearMeCheckedTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

See this example... work for me

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkedTextViewInterest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<CheckedTextView 
    android:id="@+id/nearMeCheckedTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Comment: hmm, I'ved tried it, still no go.  The checkbox on the right still remains higher than my texts.